# Should you modify the VCL file when activating deflate Gzip on the server?

Tags: magento2, varnish, gzip

When I activate Gzip I find that my site is slow, as if Varnish was not doing its job.

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Slowdown may occur if the compression takes place *before* hitting Varnish. E.g. if you have set up an NGINX SSL termination with gzip compression pointing to Varnish. As opposed to setting up compression in Varnish's backend.

Answer (score 0):

Gzip compression generally has no negative impact on Varnish's performance. Varnish will store the Gzip'ed content without performing any modifications to it and will deliver the same content to the client.

Given that Varnish actually can serve this content as a hit, it should be really fast.

Can you send me the full `varnishlog` output for the *slow* transaction? This will show where the delay is located and whether or not Varnish can actually cache the response.